# Is There a FrameworkElement.RegisterName Equivalent in WinRT?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-rt

I am developing a Windows Runtime application, and I would like to register a name for a child control (after Xaml parsing), just like I can do with WPF, using this method here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.registername%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Is this possible with Windows Runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't exist. The WinRT API and the WPF are different.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.Aspx

Comment: Yeah, no joke they are different.  WinRT is about 10% of what WPF is, it seems. No wonder its adoption is nonexistent.  Thanks for being the bearer of (yet more) bad news, in any case.